# Proving that a specific grammar is ambiguous

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars

How can I prove that the following grammar is ambiguous:

$$ A \to AA\mid B  \\  B \to aBb\mid ab $$

I tried finding a string that can be derived in two different ways, but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

The word $ababab$ can be derived in two different ways.

If you don't see why, I suggest starting with the simpler grammar $A \to AA|a$.

Comment: I dont get how you did that

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to take it from here.

Answer (score 0):

I could suggest a 6-letter word here but that would be too easy.

The productions for $B$ do not look promising. So check what can be done with $A$. Can you produce the same sequence of 3 non-terminals via 2 different derivations?